# getch() ignores first input when using screen created by newterm()

Tags: c, ubuntu, ncurses

**Update:** As suggested by Thomas in the comments, the shell definitely buffers input before ncurses can get to it.  I debugged ncurses down to the raw `read()` on the file descriptor, which I confirmed blocks until I enter two characters in the new terminal.  I did figure out an ugly hack to get around this issue -- I can preoccupy the shell with another application that doesn't interfere with the terminal (e.g., `xclock`) and then attach to the terminal.  There's no more buffering -- each character is read successfully by ncurses.

**Original Question:** I'm trying to write an ncurses program which controls multiple terminals.  I've been using the [newterm()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/initscr.html) API, which has allowed me to successfully create new SCREEN handles.  However, when I try to read input from the new terminals, [getch()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) ignores the first character I type and only returns input when entering a second character.

Here's how I've initialized my screen:

```
const char *term_fn = "/dev/pts/18"; // Filename of other terminal
FILE *term_fp = fopen(term_fn, "r+");
SCREEN *term = newterm(NULL, term_fp, term_fp);
set_term(term);                      // Ensure we're using the new screen
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);                // Make ncurses interpret function keys
nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);              // Make getch() blocking
cbreak();                            // Don't buffer input until newline
echo();                              // Echo the keyboard input back
```

I've double-checked that the file is opened correctly and ncurses initializes a new SCREEN for me.  However, when I try to read input getch() blocks until I enter 2 characters.  For example, when I run the following code which repeatedly reads & displays input until 'q' is entered:

```
void get_and_print_input() {
  char cur;
  mvprintw(0, 0, "Please enter a character: ");
  refresh();
  do {
    /* getch() will *not* return until I type 2 characters */
    cur = getch();
    if(cur != ERR) {
      mvprintw(1, 0, "Got a character: '%c'", cur);
      move(0, 26);
      refresh();
      if(cur == 'q') break;
      else cur = ERR;
    }
  } while(cur == ERR);
}
```

I get the following example output when I type 'a', wait 30 seconds and then type 'b':

```
Please enter a character: ab
Got a character: 'b'
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my TERM environment variable is "screen", although I'm using tmux.  I should note that getch() behaves as expected (i.e., returns upon entering a single character) when I use the standard screen, i.e., rather than opening a new terminal I simply call initscr().  Am I initializing the new screen incorrectly?

**Edit:** below is a self-contained example.  To run the program, I open 2 terminals -- a terminal to run the program, called terminal A, and another terminal to be controlled by ncurses, terminal B.  The program takes as input the filename for terminal B as reported by the `tty` command (e.g., I pass it `-f /dev/pts/18`).  The program, running in terminal A, opens a file descriptor & screen for controlling terminal B.  It then calls `get_and_print_input()` -- I enter characters on, and the program prints all of its output, on terminal B.  After it detects the user has entered 'q', the program cleans up all data structures & returns.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

static const char *term_fn = NULL;
static FILE *term_fp = NULL;
static SCREEN *term = NULL;

void parse_args(int argc, char **argv) {
  int c;
  while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1) {
    switch(c) {
    case 'f': term_fn = optarg; break;
    default: break;
    }
  }
}

void get_and_print_input() {
  char cur;
  mvprintw(0, 0, "Please enter a character: ");
  refresh();
  do {
    cur = getch();
    if(cur != ERR) {
      mvprintw(1, 0, "Got a character: '%c'", cur);
      move(0, 26);
      refresh();
      if(cur == 'q') break;
      else cur = ERR;
    }
  } while(cur == ERR);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  /* Set up all data structures */
  parse_args(argc, argv);
  assert(term_fn != NULL && "Must supply a terminal file");
  term_fp = fopen(term_fn, "r+");
  assert(term_fp && "Couldn't open terminal file");
  term = newterm(NULL, term_fp, term_fp);
  assert(term && "Couldn't open terminal");

  /* Configure screen */
  set_term(term);
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
  cbreak();
  echo();

  get_and_print_input();

  /* Cleanup */
  endwin();
  delscreen(term);
  fclose(term_fp);
}
```

**Edit 2:** It seems like the shell is doing some buffering before passing characters to ncurses.  When I use `noecho()` instead of `echo()`, it still echoes the first character I typed, but does not echo back the second character.  For example, using the same input as above:

```
Please enter a character: a
Got a character: 'b'
```

Comment: and what **is** `/dev/pts/18`? terminal type `screen` is correct for `tmux` as well, but is it the correct type for whatever provides `/dev/pts/18`?

Comment: `/dev/pts/18` is a pseudo-terminal.  When I open a new terminal (for example, using CTRL + Alt + T on Ubuntu), Linux creates a new pseudo-terminal device in `/dev/pts`.  You can issue the `tty` command to get the file representing the terminal, which is what I used in this example.

Comment: I knew what a pseudo-terminal **is**, I was just asking about what provided this one, as it's not obvious from just the number. So, which *terminal emulator* provides this one? I assume it's neither `screen` nor `tmux` but some graphic terminal, and therefore the terminal-type `screen` is not correct. Try `newterm("xterm", term_fp, term_fp);` for example.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood.  I'm using the "gnome-terminal" terminal emulator.  I tried both both `newterm("xterm", term_fp, term_fp);` and `newterm("gnome", term_fp, term_fp);`, but I got the same behavior.  Is there a more concrete way to detect which terminfo database entry I should be using for my terminal emulator?

Comment: From the description, that `/dev/pts/18` was created by another process, which conflicts with your application.  A **short**, self-contained/complete example would help discussion.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: But (from the description), you still have a shell running on B, which interferes with your program.

Comment: You're right, I do have a shell running in terminal B.  I guess I don't quite understand how `newterm()` is supposed to be used.  How do I prevent the shell from interfering with the application?  Or am I just using `newterm()` in an unintended way?